# Security Questions I should be asking my developers

Tags: appsec, audit, data-leakage

I am looking for a comprehensive list of security related questions I should be asking my developers. I have done some research on the net and have yet to find a great list of questions I should be asking.

For instance, questions like:

1. Is there PII or PHI data entered, accessed, stored or transmitted within your application?
2. How is data secured in Transit?
3. How is data secured at rest?
4. Who has access to the data?
5. How is sensitive data deleted?
6. How is access to your sensitive data logged?
7. Is auditing enabled, if so, provide details.
8. Can the sensitive data be exported?
   etc...

It would be awesome to have a large list that I could prune down to fit the application itself.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: - For how long is the data stored
- Medical or biometric data?

Comment: This question is not a great fit for this site. The idea here is that there can be a single acceptable answer to the question, and not a call for an evolving list.

Comment: The questions you want to ask will also highly depend on the application, the data being processed, and the risks that your organization want to address

Comment: Sean you will need to be detailed in what types of data will be handled by what application, on what system, developed in what kind of code, using what types of servers, and using what types of protocols. The moderators here are extremely picky with how specific asked questions are. Even if the question is 100% related to information security.

Comment: Mxsky - you altered the meaning of one of the lines considerably, so I fixed that.

Comment: I think this is a great question and have voted to reopen